# "home"-string(?) in terminal changed

Tags: linux, macos, terminal

So, in my Mac OS terminal, the intro letters changed from I can't even remember what they were before to `JohannasiPhone`.
[image]

I don't know what happened or what I did, but it surely wasn't intentional and I would like to reset it to the state it had before. Any suggestions?

Also, I lack the terminology of describing precisely the name of the string that changed there, so I can't add the proper tags I think. If you have suggestion how I can state the problem in more appropriate terms, please leave a comment.

Comment: It's the hostname isn't it?  Check out setting of `PS1` in `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: all right, it's indeed the hostname and it can be changed using `sudo scutil --set HostName name-you-want` as described [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/66611/how-to-change-computer-name-so-terminal-displays-it-in-mac-os-x-mountain-lion)

Comment: Well that's a different thing from changing the command line prompt.

Comment: @trojanfoe if you add your hint as an answer, I'll accept it as it was exactly the amount of information I need to solve the issue myself :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the `hostname` isn't it?

Check out setting of `PS1` in `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc`.